# KeyDown only works if I hold button clicked in UI c# metro

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have this weird problem.
I made an app which has to react to the keyboard keys (1,2,3,4,...), but it doesn't.
Well, actually it does but only if I click a button and hold it clicked, if I let it go the keys, again, stop to react.

The method I used is `KeyDown`, it is placed in `Page`

`KeyDown="Page_KeyDown"` in XAML

and in Code:

```
private void Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number1:
                {
                    KeyDownHelper(1);
                    break;
                }
        }
        ...
    }
```

It has many cases but all of them are pretty the same, and I guess that the problem isn't inside the method but with my thinking.

I think the problem is that the page kind of loses focus maybe? But not sure if that is the case and how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your app to listen for individual key presses, rather just when they key is held down, is that right? In that case you should respond to the Key Up event. That way you will be able to react to each individual key press, and ignore times when the key is held down.

Here is a link to an MSDN article on Key Up: [Key Up MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Does that help?

Comment: No, that is not the case.
It listens to all keys (why would you think different?) the problem is that, it listens only if I HOLD a BUTTON clicked in app.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. What I mean is that if you hook your code up to the KeyUp event instead of the KeyDown event then it will work how you want.

Comment: I know, thank you for that but it doesn't work, so I better say that, because if someone comes and sees and that I didn't respond he/she may think that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the CoreDispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated API.
For your reference [CoreDispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.acceleratorkeyactivated)